# Fantasy book series about a boy who finds a sword hilt that can project a blue blade, and a girl who uses a bow that can fire blue arrows of light

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a series many years ago, that every once in awhile I’ll think about, but I can’t seem to remember the name or find anything about it on the internet.

All I remember is that the main character is a young boy who finds a sword hilt; he then meets a girl whose name I believe was 'Hope.' She uses a bow but has no arrows because, as she draws the bow back, a blue arrow of light appears on the string, which she then releases. The same is true for the boy's sword hilt; as he learns to use it, he can project a blue blade from it. The antagonist/bad guy's blades are red due to their nature. I also believe the girl Hope dies and that it was a trilogy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about any of the covers?

Comment: Presumably this was written sometime after 1977...

Comment: Why, @DavidW, because the female lead is a new Hope?

Comment: I read them probably 8 years ago and i can’t remember the covers. I believe they would have been in teen fiction or fantasy as I want to say they went to “another world” one that she knew of etc but that he had no idea existed

Comment: I’m fairly certain one of the covers is the girl drawing her bow back with a blue arrow on the string